# exit for and keep looping the upper level for

Tags: vba, excel

I want to keep looping the outside for after exiting the inside for in the if statement, the logic should be right but I don't know how to code it. I did this and it gives me an "next without for" error. Ideas?

Here is my code:

```
For InrCounter = 2 To InrNum
    For ExrCounter = 2 To Exrnum

            'add missing column data from input sheet to existing sheet
            lastCofthisR = sheet1Table.Cells(ExrCounter, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            'searching for address
            If sheet1Table.Cells(InrCounter, 1) = sheet2Table.Cells(ExrCounter, 1) And sheet1Table.Cells(InrCounter, 2) = sheet2Table.Cells(ExrCounter, 2) And sheet1Table.Cells(InrCounter, 3) = sheet2Table.Cells(ExrCounter, 3) Then
                If lastCofthisR < IncNum Then
                    For LastCofRowCounter = lastCofthisR + 1 To IncNum
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ExrCounter, LastCofRowCounter) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(InrCounter, LastCofRowCounter)
                    Next LastCofRowCounter

                    'found match loop next input row
                    Exit For
                    Next InrCounter
                Else
                    'do nothing
                End If
            Else
                Next ExrCounter
                'do nothing
            End If


            'did not find the input row, find the last row of existing and add it
            lrowEx = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            For counterCofLastR = 1 To IncNum
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrowEx + 1, counterCofLastR) = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells(InrCounter, counterCofLastR)
            Next counterCofLastR
     Next InrCounter
```

Comment: well that means your missing a Next statment.  So at the top you have to for statements but at the bottom you only close out 1, add another Next statement at the point where it should loop.

Comment: In VBA, you'll have to resort to `GoTo` to jump out of the inner loop to the outer.

Comment: I put the other next statement at the bottom of the code. I don't know how to jump out side of the inner for in the if statement. @Sorcei

Comment: "To keep looping the outside `for` after exiting the inside `for`" - Doesn't `Exit For` inside an `If` on the inner loop do exactly that?

Comment: @FabioPereira yes but I got a error msg saying "next without for"

Comment: @user2600411 Then just recheck your code as Ripster suggested. You use `Next` in VB only to close the `For` clause and loop - e.g. would be something like an "end for" - you can't use it INSIDE the loop to skip to the next counter, or exit the loop - for that you use `Exit For`. I couldn't understand exactly what your code does, but you can try and use `Do While...Loop` instead of `For...Next` for some added flexibility (and some complexity, since you have to update the counter yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start a `For` loop and then have the `Next` statement embedded in an `If` statement.

Example:

```
For i = 0 To 10
    If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    Next
End If
```

Will throw an error because Next is inside the if statement. The proper way to do this would be:

```
For i = 0 To 10
    If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    End If
Next
```

It also looks like you have one too many Next statements.

Edit:

To jump out of a loop you can use `Exit For`

For example:

```
For i = 0 To 10
    For x = 0 To 10
        Exit For
        Debug.Print x
    Next
    Debug.Print i
Next
```

only `i` will get printed 0 to 10 since the inner loop will hit `Exit For`

If you want to skip a loop iteration you can manually increment the loop counter. For example the following code will skip `5` because `i` is immediately increased at the beginning of the loop.

```
For i = 0 To 10
    If i = 5 Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Debug.Print i
Next
```

Comment: The logic would be different if I made the change you posted. The if statement finds a match and if it is found i wanna jump out of inner loop i don't know how to do that.@Ripster

Comment: I updated my answer to explain some ways that you can try to achieve the same logic.